# How to write this macro in cpp that can return from the function

Tags: c++, variant

I'm using cpp variants to indicate error in my program, for example, I have a function like this:

```
std::variant<Result, Error> do_foo();

std::variant<string, Error> do_bar() {
  auto v = do_foo();
  if (std::holds_alternative<Error>(v)) {
    return std::get<Error>(v);
  }
  auto r = std::get<Result>(v);
  // do some more stuff with r
  return some_str;
}
```

But I ended up checking for error so many times and it is tedious, so I wanted to write a macro, let's call it bail, to shorten it. So do_bar could look like this:

```
std::variant<string, Error> do_bar() {
  Result r = bail(do_foo()); // it should return if do_foo() returns an error
  // do some more stuff with r
  return some_str;
}
```

Not sure how to write that macro though, here is some attempt that doesn't work:

```
#define bail(v) { auto _v = v; \
  if (_v.index() == 1) return std::get<1>(_v); \
  std::get<0>(_v); }
```

However, that block doesn't give me any value. Note that I'm trying to avoid exceptions. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to avoid exceptions? Because this is what exceptions are used for.

Comment: Macros bad. Use a lambda.

Comment: @Casey lambda doesn't let me return the outer function. I would love to know if that is not true.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Exceptions are ugly as hell. A lot of people avoid exceptions in C++, for example, google largely banned exceptions from their codebase.

Comment: GCC has [statement expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) as an extension, but it's not portable.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks, that could work, I wish that was a standard c++ feature though. I would prefer something that also compiles on other stuff, mainly clang.

Comment: The merits of exceptions are entirely a matter of personal opinions. Google is wrong. Exceptions are a unique and a fundamental part of C++, and when used appropriately they are just one of the many tools in one's arsenal of C++ skills. There's nothing wrong with exceptions when they are used correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want isn't possible in portable C++.  If you are using gcc or clang, you can use [statement exprs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html).  I really recommend you don't do this, but here is the answer to the question you asked:

```
// Non-portable--you probably shouldn't do this
#define bail(v) ({            \
    auto _v = v;              \
    if (_v.index() == 1)      \
      return std::get<1>(_v); \
    std::get<0>(_v);          \
  })
```